# Fast diff implementation in C++ to get amount of line differences in large files

Tags: c++, performance, diff

Searched but didn't seem to find exactly what I needed.

I'm looking for a fast C++ equivalent of running the following command:

```
diff file1.log file2.log | wc -l
```

At present, I'm using file pipes in order to run diff from the command line, however I need to do this in a large, multi-nested loop and it takes quite longer than I anticipated.  The files being diffed are roughly 150-200mb each, and each diff takes roughly 1-2 minutes.

Is there a faster solution that can be rolled by C++?

Here is my present method of calling it:

```
static std::string run_cmd(std::string in)
{
  // run command
  FILE* pipe = popen(in.c_str(), "r");
  if (!pipe)  return "err";

  char buff[128];
  std::string res = "";
  while (!feof(pipe))
  {
    if (fgets(buff, 128, pipe) != NULL)
      res += buff;
  }
  pclose(pipe);
  return res;
}

// diff 2 given files and return line number differences
std::string fileDiff(std::string file1, std::string file2)
{
  std::string f1 = base + file1;
  std::string f2 = base + file2;
  std::string cmd = "diff " + f1 + " " + f2 + " | wc -l";

  std::string res = run_cmd(cmd);
  if (res == "err") 
    return "E: Diff on [" + f1 + "] and [" + f2 + "]";

  return res;
}
```

---

Edit:

What I am essentially doing is logging code coverage.  I've inserted logging statements into each nook and cranny of the codebase I'm working in, and writing each run to its own log file.  I've attempted to minimize the writing penalty by not including them in constructors, loops, etc, and have buffered the actual writing process.

The program I had typically took about 10 minutes to run.  With my added logging and diff calls its scaled up to about ~1 day.

I only care about the amount of line differences in this case, as it is feeding a fitness function in a genetic algorithm.  The spread of execution paths between iterations is important at this point.

Comment: You're probably not going to get performance much better than the diff command.  It is already built in a compiled language.

Comment: I think your only hope of making this faster is to exploit something specific about the structure of your files.  For example, if you know that your differences will only occur at specific columns, you could reduce the amount of text to compare.

Comment: Quarter of a gigabyte is not going to be a sneeze to diff. It is possible that you are trying to solve wrong solution to a problem more efficiently. What is the reason why you diff them?

Comment: edited question for more information about reasoning why

Comment: Is there any possibility of reducing the amount of data that has to be read?  (e.g. by making the length of the text-lines shorter, and/or generating fewer of them)   Adding more RAM to the computer might help as well, since file I/O will be much faster if the file is cached in RAM rather than actually being read off the drive.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I could, but the string I'm generating to be written really needs to capture things like filename, namespace, class, function, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching an external process is fast.  At 1-2 minutes per file, the process spawn overhead is a tiny insignificant fraction.  You must be limited by 1) the performance of the diff command or 2) inefficient reading and storing of the pipe's output data. Try running the diff command in the shell and outputting into a file.  Is it much faster?  If not, then 1).  If so, then 2).

I don't know much about Unix pipes, but a 128-byte buffer sounds small.  The diff command is old and widely used, so it's unlikely that you could write a faster version.

Comment: Another answer from left field: is it possible that you could replace this part of your program with a shell script?  If you use xargs, etc. you can rely on the shell implementing pipes quickly.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, I'm interested in what you found out.  Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possibilities.

One is to simplify the problem. `diff` does quite a bit of work to find the minimal set of edits to transform one file into another. If you just want to know how many lines are different between the two files, and don't care about how one transformed into the other, you *may* be able to gain some speed by simply building a set of the lines in each file, and getting the size of the `set_symmetric_difference` between them.

The second is that if you're looking (for example) for the files that are most/least similar, right now you're probably re-doing the diff between every file and every other file. In other words, you have an quadratic problem, and given N files, you're re-reading each file N times.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish and the number of files, there's a good chance you can read each file only once. For example, if you hash each line, and just store a set of hashes, you can probably fit the data for all the files in memory at once, so the quadratic part of the operation can happen entirely in memory instead of rereading every file many times.